# Why doesn’t my truck crank up after I changed the starter,neutral safety switch and starter relay?

Tags: ford, truck, no-crank-no-start

I had my truck stored away for about a year and the battery went bad so I changed it,but the truck didn’t crank until I put it on neutral or sometimes it would start on park.Today I had the neutral safety switch replaced and the starter too as well as the starter relay,but no crank just clicking in the fuse box.I’ve tried charging battery and turning the ignition on and off but no good results.Any suggestions?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 2):

Clean all of the battery connections and ensure they are tight. This includes the batter and terminal connectors, wire ends at the solenoid, wires to the starter, and wherever else you can find they run. If it connects somehow to the battery, clean and tighten. Also check to ensure there are no bulges in the battery cables. This indicates corrosion, which will block the flow of electrons. If there are any bulges (in any of the power cables coming from the battery) replace them.